# android: Actionbar for tabactivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabactivity

I have a tabactivity with two tabs. I have added an action bar to this main activity ( tabactivity ). The search should happen in the corresponding child activity. How this can be implemented. Whichever is the current tab, search should be on that current activity

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`TabActivity` is deprecated. Use `Fragmentactivity` instead of `TabActivity`.

Get the current tab , based on that implement search

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {   
    static TabHost mytabs;

    mytabs = getTabHost();
        mytabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         
                Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());
            }       
        });
```

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated.

Comment: Then use Fragment activity instead of TabActivity

Comment: Dude. Don't tell me. Edit your answer so OP will understand it.